# Issues with main function and error messages

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I'm writing a program using two functions and an array to show ranges of inputted data. I've got the majority of this done, but I'm getting a few error messages that I can't figure out, and I'm having a hard time with my main function. Any ideas?

```
 /* program to display frequency counts of traffic accidents */ 

#include <stdio.h>

void updateRange(int accident, int accident_range[]);
void displayRange(int accident_range[]);

int main(void)
{
int accident;
const int SIZE = 6;
int accident_range[SIZE];
  while (accident < SIZE)
  {
      accident_range[accident] = 0;
    ++accident;
  }    
  updateRange(&accident, &accident_range);           
  displayRange(&accident_range[]);

return(0);
}


void updateRange(int accident, int accident_range[])
{
accident = 0;   
     do
{
    printf("Enter an accident count (negative to end):");
    scanf("%d", &accident);

    if (accident == -1)
        break;

        else if(accident >= 0 && accident <= 99)
        accident_range[0]++;

        else if(100 <= accident && accident <= 199)
         accident_range[1]++;

        else if(200 <= accident && accident <= 299)
         accident_range[2]++;

        else if(300 <= accident && accident <= 399)
         accident_range[3]++;

        else if(400 <= accident && accident <= 499)
         accident_range[4]++;

        else
         accident_range[5]++;

 } while (accident != -1);
}

void displayRange(int accident_range[])
{
    printf("Range       Frequency            \n" ) ; 
    printf("   0-99             %d\n", accident_range[0]);
    printf("100-199             %d\n", accident_range[1]);  
    printf("200-299             %d\n", accident_range[2]); 
    printf("300-399             %d\n", accident_range[3]); 
    printf("400-499             %d\n", accident_range[4]); 
    printf("500 or above        %d\n", accident_range[5]); 
}
```

Comment: 1) `while (accident < SIZE)` accident is not initialised. 2) `updateRange(&accident, &accident_range);  ` updateRange expects an int, not a pointer. 3) accident_range already decays into a pointer.

Comment: ** Please cut/paste the error messages **

Comment: Note that if you are using a C89 compiler such as MSVC, you will not be allowed to write `const int SIZE = 6;
int accident_range[SIZE];` because it uses a (not very variable-length) VLA or variable-length array.  In C++ (a very different language), you'd be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
updateRange(&accident, &accident_range);           
displayRange(&accident_range[]);
```

Should actually be just:

```
updateRange(accident, accident_range);           
displayRange(accident_range);
```

`updateRange` takes a pointer and an array. You are passing the address of the pointer and the address of the array which doesn't make any sense. Just pass them directly.

Similar story for `displayRange` which also expects an array. `&accident_range[]` doesn't make any sense (and it doesn't compile). Your statment is passing the address of a value in an array that you have not specified e.g. `&accident_range[0]` will pass the address of the value at position 0 which you don't want. Just pass `accident_range` directly.

Finally you should initialise `accident` to something before you use it. I'm assuming you want it initialised to 0.

After all that I got the loop to behave normally.

Comment: @wingsofmaybe No problems, hope this has fixed it properly :)

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the following problems in your code:

```
int accident;
//...
while (accident < SIZE)
```

you don't initialize accident.

```
  updateRange(&accident, &accident_range);           
  displayRange(&accident_range[]);
```

the parameter in displayRange is bad syntax, additionally you don't need to de-reference the array. (since you also don't seem to need 'int accident' in updateRange, you should probably remove it as parameter.

```
void updateRange(int accident_range[]);
void displayRange(int accident_range[]);

  updateRange(accident_range);           
  displayRange(accident_range);
```

in function updateRange(), you should also add a check to the while loop, to make sure it will never write out of the array:

```
 int count = 0;
 do { 
 //....
 } while (accident >=0 && ++count < SIZE);
```

Also the description text of your program says the loop exits if you enter a negative number, but in fact it only exits the loop if '-1' was entered.

Please note that you should remove the const int size variable from your main and change it to a define:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6
```